# Does $\frac{a \times \frac{b}{2} \times c}{d}$ simplify to $\frac{abc}{2d}$, or to $\frac{abcd}{2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

Which of these two ways of simplifying $y=\dfrac{a\times\frac{b}{2}\times c}{d}$ is correct, and why?

1st way:

$$\begin{align}
y &=\frac{a \times \frac{b}{2} \times c}{d} \\[4pt]
\implies\quad y &=\frac{\frac{abc}{2}}{d} \tag1 \\[4pt]
\implies\quad y &=\frac{abc}{2} \div d \tag2 \\[4pt]
\implies\quad y &=\frac{abc}{2d} \tag3
\end{align}$$

2nd way:

$$\begin{align}
y&=\frac{a \times \frac{b}{2} \times c}{d}  \\[4pt]
\implies\quad y&=\frac{\frac{abc}{2}}{d} \tag4 \\[4pt]
\implies\quad y&=abc \div \frac{2}{d} \tag5 \\[4pt]
\implies\quad y&=\frac{abcd}{2} \tag6
\end{align}$$

Comment: the first one is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct method is the first way. It all comes down to order of operations. Recall that mathematical expressions in parentheses come before multiplication and division. So when we write
$$\frac{\frac{abc}{2}}{d}$$
we're saying:
$$(abc/2)/d$$
because the fraction bar between the $2$ and $d$ is largest.

This fractional expression is equivalent to
$$\frac{\frac{abc}{2}}{\frac{d}{1}} = \frac{abc}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{d} = \frac{abc}{2d}$$

The second way is evaluating $$abc/(2/d),$$
which changes the location of the parentheses.